# should I call declarative_base() multiple times?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I participate in a legacy project which is python Flask API with sqlalchemy.
In this project I can see there are many calls to `declarative_base()` for creating base for db classes.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
    
class ExampleClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example_table_name'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'some_schema'}
    vendor_id = Column(String())
```

And in many modules with db classes, there is this `declarative_base()` called.
We have some performance issues in this project, sometimes db acts very slow. Is it possible that multiple instances of classes created via calls to `declarative_base()` may be the reason?

Comment: make a single base call and use that object in all model

Comment: I think doing what sahasrara62 said is a good idea. I can't imagine that the performance issues you're experiencing have anything to do with declarative_base though. But I'd make the change either way, then you can rule it out.

Comment: I think inefficient queries would be a more likely cause. This sqlalchemy article on performance might be helpful https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/performance.html#how-can-i-profile-a-sqlalchemy-powered-application.

Comment: @sahasrara62 - clean code principles would indicate so, indeed. But you didn't provide any other arguments for using a single instance.

Comment: in `__init__.py` you can make `Base = declarative_base()` and there interit this object in your own `base class` and then use that base class everywher in the models